# integrate and differentiate more complicated functions in python using sympy

Tags: python, sympy

When I try to integrate or differentiate some more complicated functions using sympy, it doesn't return the algebraic expression and instead returns something like Derivative(arctanh(x), x).

Here's a MWE:

```
from sympy import *
x=symbols("x")
print(diff("arctanh(x)"))
```

How can I overcome this?

Comment: trig functions are found in https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SymPy the function is called `atanh` rather than `arctanh`:

```
In [1]: diff(atanh(x))
Out[1]: 
  1   
──────
     2
1 - x 

In [2]: diff("atanh(x)")
Out[2]: 
  1   
──────
     2
1 - x
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that, would you mind letting me know where I can find a list of these commands? Also, what about other complicated functions such as e**sin(x)?

Comment: @Pseudonym123 What about them?

Comment: You can use `dir(sympy)` to see a list of 1000 or so SymPy functions.